# Go straight to another view controller (without generating the floating button options)on clicking the floating button(ActionButton)

Tags: ios, swift, floating-action-button

I am using the third party `ActionButton` to show a floating button in my app. Now when I click on the floating button, I want to go to another `viewcontroller` directly i.e. I don't want to generate the options that normally show up when a floating button is clicked and I want to go to another `viewcontroller` straight.

And once again, I am using the third party `ActionButton`. People who have used this third-party can maybe catch the issue faster...:)

Thanks in advance....:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be fixed...

We use the third-party `ActionButton` to show a floating button for any view like so...

```
actionButton = ActionButton(attachedToView: self.view, items: [])
actionButton.action = { button in
            //the viewcontroller to be shown can be loaded here...     
nil)
```

Here, in the first line, the `items` array has all all the options to display while clicking on the floating button. But in case we don't want any options to come up when we click on the floating button, the `items` array can be left blank as I have done here.

Then in `actionButton.action` above, we can load the required view controller, as I have indicated above.

Doing this results in going directly to the `viewcontroller` of our choice while clicking on the floating button without the options coming up...